# How to reduce array of numbers to an array with given length with with low information loss

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, interpolation

I'm building an audio app for iOS and I need to capture audio from the mic and visualize it. I'm using AudioKit to receive amplitude data (from AKAmplitudeTracker) every 0.1 sec and store it to an array. This results in nice precision, but this results in 600 values/minute to be stored in array. I'm building a waveform plot from data stored in this array, and its impossible to keep needed appearance with thousands of waveforms. I'm looking for a way to reduce number of elements in array with low information loss to a given specific number, like 256 or 512. I'm unfamiliar with terminology of this field so any help is appreciated.

Comment: The technique to use is `downsampling`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resample the array by choosing evenly spaced samples.  Here is a little generic routine that does that:

```
func resample<T>(array: [T], toSize newSize: Int) -> [T] {
    let size = array.count
    return (0 ..< newSize).map { array[$0 * size / newSize] }
}
```

**Downsample example:**

```
// Create array [0, 1, 2, ..., 98, 99, 100]    
let arr = (0...100).map { $0 }

// Downsample it to 15 items    
let sampled = resample(array: arr, toSize: 15)
print(sampled)
```

> ```
> [0, 6, 13, 20, 26, 33, 40, 47, 53, 60, 67, 74, 80, 87, 94]
> ```

**Upsample example:**

```
// Create array [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
let arr2 = (0...4).map { $0 }

// Upsample it to 15 items
let sampled2 = resample(array: arr2, toSize: 15)
print(sampled2)
```

> ```
> [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
> ```

Comment: Worth pointing out, especially since OP is working with digital audio, that directly downsampling without first applying an appropriate filter (e.g. low-pass filter) can lead to aliasing (direct downsampling will not fulfil the [Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist–Shannon_sampling_theorem)).

Comment: Although, in this case he's not really dealing with audio any more since it's already been down sampled to a 10hz sample rate.